# Contest Math: construct equations with$ \sum_{i=1}^k a_i = \prod_{j=1}^ka_j$ where $a_k$ are all positive rational number.

Tags: contest-math

The question is to find all possible integer n such that there exists at least 2 positive rational numbers $a_k$ such that $n =  \sum_{i=1}^k a_i = \prod_{j=1}^ka_j.$

What I think is obvious is, for any composite numbers >=6, they all qualify because as long as you can find a pair of $a_1$ and $a_2$ whose $* = n$ but $+\leq n$, you can use $*1$ to make addition side up.

However, the remaining is quite hard, because $a_n$ can be non-integer, my current guess is as long as you use some 1/n, you need to pay back n*times. But I stuck here for like a day...

Comment: Is the $n$ supposed to be the same ?

Comment: yes, is $n$ the index of the last term or is $n$ the value of the left and right-hand sides (the sum and the product)?

Comment: I've updated my question, I made a typo, actually, k can be arbitrary but the job is to judge each positive integer n to see if they can be assembled in the following way.

Comment: Why **2** positive rational numbers  $a_k$? What do you mean?

Comment: The 2 mentioned in the second paragraph are basically an example to show why all composite number larger than or equal to 6 will obviously fulfill.

Comment: @WWMASK I propose you leave this question as it was originally and ask the new one with the un-fixed number of summands/products, and add a link to that version here.

Comment: I also uploaded my lastest progress.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the AM-GM inequality

$$n = \sum_{i=1}^na_n \ge n\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^na_i} =n\sqrt[n]{n}
\iff n \ge n\sqrt[n]{n} \iff 1 \ge n$$

So, the necessary condition is $n=1$. And of course, this is also the sufficient condition.

**Conclusion**: $n = 1$ is the unique solution.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, actually it's k as and the number of a has nothing to do with the n.

Comment: Oh yeah this was correct, sorry

Comment: Who downvote me? If you have courage, explain why you do that.

Comment: I didn't downvote it. It was a good answer, only the OP flip-flopped on the statement, even though I asked him what was up 15 minuetes ago. But w/e

Comment: To my mind anyone who downvotes is a coward, so I would not hold my breath :(

Comment: I didn't and I uploaded it to cancel things out, it's my bad to post a question with a typo

Comment: Don't worry about it, it happens @WWMASK :)

Answer (score 2):

I just got something more, now, for any even number >=4, it's obviously all of them can be written as such $2*n*1$...as many as you need...$*1$, for odd number >= 9, they are also fine. This is because, for any n, you can always write it as $n/2*(4)*(1/2)*1...$ as many as you want $*1$, the only restriction is the $4*1/2$ term, which means $n/2>=4+1/4 = 9$.

So for now, we only actually need to check 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, and 1 and 2 is obviously not possible.

So the remaining question is if 3, 5, 7 can be represented as the form mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer (a supplement to the OP's answer). Notice that by the AGM (just as in the NNP's deleted answer):

$$n \geq k n^{\frac1k},$$

$$n^{1-\frac1k} \geq k.$$

Now, if $n=3,$ then

$$3^{1-\frac1k}\geq k.$$ The LHS is at most 2, and $\sqrt{3} < 2,$ so an impossibility.

For $5,$ $$5^{1-\frac1k} \geq k.$$ So, $k$ can only be equal to $2,$ and it is easy to check that this is impossible.$

For $7,$$ $$7^{1-\frac1k}\geq k,$ which means that $$7 \geq k^{k/(k-1)},$$ which means $k=2, 3, 4.$ $2$ is clearly impossible, but $3, 4$ are not obviously so.